# Listener implementation: 3 EditTexts in a single Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, listener

Goal of this code:

I have a fragment layout with 3 EditTexts :

- Multi-line description
- a decimal amount
- a date.

I wish a user to enter this information using the software keyboard and then the Fragment return a newItem (record) to the parent Activity so it can be stored in a db.

1. Am I taking the right approach using a Listener?

   `onEditorActionListener` seems more flexible than an `onKeyListener`.
2. Eclipse really isn't happy with the line:

   `descriptionEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);`

   complaining that the `setOnEditorActionListener` is not applicable with the arguments.

I'm assuming this means I have a problem here:

```
public interface OnEditorActionListener {
    public void onNewItemAdded(String[] newItem);
    // need to change this newItem?
}
```

Any other comments welcome as this is my first attempt at trying this and I'm sure it's awful.

**Full code below.**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AddNewItemTextFragment extends Fragment {

    // A Fragment event callback interface, pg 126 Meier; used to share info with host Activity
    // Host activity listens for a new item to be created

    public interface OnEditorActionListener {
        public void onNewItemAdded(String[] newItem);
        // need to change this newItem?
    }

    // Create a variable to store a reference to the parent Activity that will implement the interface.

    private OnEditorActionListener onEditorActionListener;  

    // This reference can be retrieved as soon as the parent has been bound to the Fragment with the Fragment's onAttach handler.

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            onEditorActionListener = (OnEditorActionListener)activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
          throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "must implement OnEditorActionListener");
        }
    }

    // The Listener implementation

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstaceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_new_item_text_fragment , container, false);

        final EditText descriptionEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        descriptionEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
        final EditText amountEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.amount);
        amountEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
        final EditText dateEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.date1);
        dateEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
        // add category, sub category Spinner


        // need to add newItem as a parameter?      
        descriptionEditText.setOnEditorActionListener (new OnEditorActionListener() {

            public boolean onEditorAction (TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                boolean handled = false;

                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
                        String newDescription = descriptionEditText.getText().toString();
                        String newAmount = amountEditText.getText().toString();
                        String newDate = dateEditText.getText().toString();
                        // add other fields here; create array newItem containing all fields
                        String [] newItem ={newDescription, newAmount, newDate};

                        onEditorActionListener.onNewItemAdded(newItem);
                        handled = true;
                    }
                return handled;  

            }


        });
        return view;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me suggest another approach.

Add a button to your Fragment layout.
Name it **addNewItem** `("@+id/addNewItem")`.
This button allow user to add a new item.

Declare the Interface that activity must implement:

```
public interface OnAddNewItemListener {
    public void onNewItemAdded(String[] newItem);
}
```

Your Fragment class:

```
public class AddNewItemTextFragment extends Fragment {

    // A Fragment event callback interface, pg 126 Meier; used to share info with host Activity
    // Host activity listens for a new item to be created

    public interface OnAddNewItemListener {
        public void onNewItemAdded(String[] newItem);
    }

    // Create a variable to store a reference to the parent Activity that will implement the interface.

    private OnAddNewItemListener onAddNewItemListener;  

    // This reference can be retrieved as soon as the parent has been bound to the Fragment with the Fragment's onAttach handler.

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            onAddNewItemListener = (OnAddNewItemListener)activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
          throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "must implement OnEditorActionListener");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_new_item_text_fragment , container, false);

        final EditText descriptionEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        final EditText amountEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.amount);
        final EditText dateEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.date1);
        final Button addNewItemButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.addNewItem);    

        // onClickListener for button
        addNewItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            // need to add newItem as a parameter?
            String newDescription = descriptionEditText.getText().toString();
            String newAmount = amountEditText.getText().toString();
            String newDate = dateEditText.getText().toString();

           // add other fields here; create array newItem containing all fields
            String [] newItem ={newDescription, newAmount, newDate};

            // call method on Interface(activity)
            onAddNewItemListener.onNewItemAdded(newItem);
           }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

Implement the Interface in activity.
When addNewItem button is clicked the method `onNewItemAdded` is called in activity.

Comment: Great, after reading through all your changes I liked them: to summarise, you renamed the interface (thanks) and the button you added acts to  'return' the whole record, avoiding the need for multiple listeners    (thanks also for tidying my original submission)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you define the interface OnEditorActionListener with the same name as the TextView.OnEditorActionListener. If you would like to use the second one, than you should explicitly write the TextView prefix before it.

For example:

```
public class AddNewItemTextFragment extends Fragment implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener
```

...with this the next code will work:

```
descriptionEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
```

...or this:

```
 descriptionEditText.setOnEditorActionListener (new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

            public boolean onEditorAction (TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
...
```

Comment: Thanks this is a definitely useful comment. I haven't tried it but EditView.OnEditorActionListener should also work as well as TextView. , no?

Comment: Yes, EdiText extends the TextView so the OnEditorActionListener is the same.